# nightwatch test not continuing after one Timed out failure

Tags: nightwatch.js

Whenever an element isn't found i get a assertion timeout failure that halts tests that will follow.. I already set the necessary setting but still unable to find a solution for this.

my test setting

```
  test_settings : {
    skip_testcases_on_fail: false,
    end_session_on_fail: false,
    default : {
      launch_url : "http://localhost",
      selenium_port  : 4444,
      selenium_host  : "localhost",
      silent: true,
      screenshots : {
        enabled : false,
        path : ""
      },
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        acceptSslCerts: true,
        nativeEvents: true,
        chromeOptions : {
          args : ["headless"]
       }
      }
    },

    chrome : {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `skip_testcases_on_fail: false,` inside default and it should do the job. Your test settings should look like this:

```
test_settings : {
        end_session_on_fail: false,
default : {
        skip_testcases_on_fail: false,
        launch_url : "http://localhost",
            selenium_port  : 4444,
            selenium_host  : "localhost",
            silent: true,
            screenshots : {
            enabled : false,
                path : ""
        },
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                acceptSslCerts: true,
                nativeEvents: true,
                chromeOptions : {
                args : ["headless"]
            }
        }
    },

    chrome : {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: "chrome"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that says you can use the `verify` function instead of `assert`, in which case the suite will continue to run upon a failure.  [use verify instead of assert](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nightwatchjs/t79Nrreqpj8)

Also, you could just use the `--retries` flag and supply it with the number of times you want a test case to execute after it fails.